# How to properly type this `makeCancellable` function and make Flowtype stop complaining?

Tags: javascript, promise, flowtype

I have a following function to make Promises cancellable. As you can see, I have defined a `CancellablePromise` interface that extends the original `Promise` and I have some type-checking functions marked with `%checks` to check if a value is a Promise or if it's already a cancellable promise. The main `makeCancellable` function is supposed to take a `Promise` as an argument and return a `CancellablePromise`. Everything **works** as expected, but I had to use `$FlowFixMe` annotations in 3 places because Flow was complaining no matter what I've tried. (Please read comments in the code below to see what Flow is complaining about).

What bugs me the most is the very first `isCancellable` check where I check if the promise is already a `CancellablePromise`. Strangely, if I mark the function's `originalPromise` argument as `any`, as `CancellablePromise<*> | number` or whatever else, the typechecking system sees that the `isCancellable` function is a type guard and stops complaining. When the `originalPromise` argument is typed as in the code example below, somehow Flow ignores the fact that `isCancellable` is a properly typed type guard and starts complaining just as if the `%checks` type guard is not there.

I would appreciate any help. Did't have issues like this when I was using TypeScript some time ago - type guarding and typecasting worked wonderfully there, but somehow I can't get make Flow to cooperate.

```
interface CancellablePromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    cancel: Function
};

function isThenable(value: any): boolean %checks {
    return typeof value === 'object' && 'then' in value;
}

function isCancellable(promise: any): boolean %checks {
    return isThenable(promise) && 'cancel' in promise;
}

function makeCancellable(originalPromise: CancellablePromise<*> | Promise<*>): CancellablePromise<*> {
    if (isCancellable(originalPromise)) {
        // $FlowFixMe
        return originalPromise; // <- complains here because Promise type does not have `cancel` method, ignores the isCancellable %checks
    }

    let resolvePromise;
    let rejectPromise;
    let cancelled = false;

    const cancellable = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolvePromise = resolve;
        rejectPromise = reject;
    });

    // $FlowFixMe
    // Complains here because Promise cannot have 'cancel' method
    // Typecasting with (cancellable: CancellablePromise<*> does not work
    cancellable.cancel = () => {
        cancelled = true;
    }

    originalPromise.then(result => {
        cancelled || resolvePromise(result);
    }).catch(reason => {
        cancelled || rejectPromise(reason);
    });

    // $FlowFixMe
    // Complains here because Promise lacks 'cancel' method because adding the method and typecasting does not work
    return cancellable;
};
```

Comment: AFAIK typescript does better job of typing promises. I am **not** 100% sure about this specific case

Comment: which promise library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Promise` is a class, and classes in Flow are nominal types (unlike in Typescript where they are structural types like interfaces). In Flow the only way to add fields to a type that is a class is to create a subclass. For example,

```
class CancellablePromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    cancelled = false;
    cancel() { this.cancelled = true; }
};
```

You could additionally define an interface with the `then` and `cancel` signatures. The issue with an interface that extends a class is that any value of the interface type must be an instance of `Promise` or of a subclass of `Promise`. That reduces the usefulness of an interface over a subclass. In Typescript a class can be used as an interface, but Flow works differently in that respect.

The subclass form of `CancellablePromise` can be instantiated directly:

```
const cancellable = new CancellablePromise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolvePromise = resolve;
    rejectPromise = reject;
});
```